# Why does __proto__ not update when prototype is set to null

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I've been trying to learn the differences between the `.__proto__` and the `.prototype` properties. From what I have read, the `.__proto__` property is available on instances, which points to a reference of the protoype object that was used to construct it. With that in mind, I pictured it behaving something like so:

```js
let prototype = {};
let proto = prototype;
prototype = null;
console.log(prototype); // null (expected)
console.log(proto); // {} (expected)
```

When I set `prototype` to `null`, the `proto` variable still holds a reference to the original `prototype` object, so the last log prints `{}` as expected, this is how I currently understand the below code to function, and prints out the expected result:

```js
function Foo() {
  this.x = 1;
}

Foo.prototype = null; // same as prototype = null above
const obj = new Foo();
console.log(obj.__proto__); // still points to default object (expected, based on above snippet behaviour)
```

However, with the above in mind, what confuses me why does assigning the prototype also change `__proto__`. When we assigned `.prototype` to a new object reference , shouldn't `__proto__` keep hold of the previous object it was refering and not change to the new object?

```js
function Foo() {
  this.x = 1;
}

Foo.prototype = {y: 2}; // same as prototype = null above
const obj = new Foo();
console.log(obj.__proto__); // expected {}, but instead got {y: 2}
```

Why isn't the above `.__proto__` pointing to the original prototype object (like it does in the second code snippet), but instead pointing to the newly assinged `prototype` object?

Comment: If you call `new` on a function, whose `prototype` property isn't an object (e.g. `null`), [the prototype will be a default](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-getprototypefromconstructor), in this case `%Object.prototype%`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte ahh, I see. So the prototype isn't actually being used as null, it instead gets used object as the default object.

Comment: A reference to the prototype will be added on every instance, as an internal property, which the [deprecated (!) legacy property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) `__proto__` exposes as a normal property. Changing `Foo.prototype` after an instance has been created won't change the prototype of that instance. You can however, as with all objects in javascript, mutate the prototype object (change properties), which would be reflected on all instances, but is not something you should normally do.